# How do I put different priors on different levels of a categorical variable in brms?

Tags: r, regression, bayesian

This is a just a coding query from a bayesian novice.

I have a model of this type:

```
response ~ pred + (1 | participant) + (1 | item)  # pred = {level1, level2, level3} [ref level = level1]
```

I’m using brms. I’d like to put different priors on the three levels of pred. Suppose these are the priors:

- intercept (level1): N ~ (1,1)
- effect of level2 relative to level1: N ~ (0,1)
- effect of level3 relative to level1: N ~ (-1,1)

I think I know how to set up the prior for level1; what I’m having trouble with is setting up the two different priors for level2 and level3. With my limited brms skills, this is the closest that I can get:

```
prior1 <- c(
prior(normal(1, 1), class = Intercept), # level1
prior(normal(0, 1), class = b, coef = weight) # prior for level 2, but specified as if there is no level3        
)
```

As you can see, I don’t know what to do with level3.

Apparently, it is possible to do this in Stan. (Unfortunately, I’m not proficient with Stan.) I’ve found the following code somewhere:

```
// prior specifications
b[1] ~ normal (0, 1);
b[2] ~ normal (-1, 1);
temp_Intercept ~ normal (1, 1)
```

In short, could someone possibly show me how to modify my brms code above so that I can set up separate priors for level2 and level3?

I’d be extremely grateful for any help with this. I did find [this earlier query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59020123/brms-how-do-i-set-prior-on-categorical-variable), but I'm not sure if it's relevant to my query.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `get_prior()` to see the priors that you can specify for a given model. Here is an example with the `iris` data-set included with R. You specify the model and the data to be used like this:

```
get_prior(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
```

Which gives this output:

```
                   prior     class              coef group resp dpar nlpar bound
1                                b                                              
2                                b Speciesversicolor                            
3                                b  Speciesvirginica                            
4 student_t(3, 5.8, 2.5) Intercept                                              
5   student_t(3, 0, 2.5)     sigma
```

We can see here that we can specify 2 of the 3 levels of `Species`. The `coef` for the first level alphabetically corresponds to the Intercept , and the `coef` names for the other two levels are specified. You should therefore be able to specify different priors for `versicolor` and `virginica` like this:

```
priors <- c(
prior(normal(1, 1), class = Intercept),
prior(normal(0, 1), class = b, coef = Speciesversicolor),
prior(normal(0, 1), class = b, coef = Speciesvirginica)
)
```

Note that this is just example code that is closest to your code, as I couldn't reproduce the code you included. Running `get_prior()` should give you the details you need to fit different priors for each level of your predictor.